# Why does this cause error CS4011: type arguments cannot be inferred from usage?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I have the following sample.

```
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var varc = new C();
      // Error CS0411
      var varf1b = varc.F1(t => new { City = t.City }, (t, v) => v + t.Status, (g, a) => new { City = g.City, Bigstatus = a });
      // compiles OK
      var varf1a = varc.F1(t => new { City = t.City }, (C t, int v) => v + t.Status, (g, a) => new { City = g.City, Bigstatus = a });

      // now replace varc by an anonymous class -- how to solve it now?
      var varanon = new { };

    }
  }

  public class C {
    public string City;
    public int Status;
  }

  public static class X {
    public static T1 F1<T2, T3, T4, T1>(
      this T2 s,
      Func<T2, T3> g,
      Func<T2, T4, T4> a,
      Func<T3, T4, T1> r)
      where T2 : class where T3 : class where T1 : class {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The first call triggers error CS0411. I cannot fix this by the usual method, which is adding in the type arguments, because it uses anonymous types. Fortunately adding types to one of the lambdas seems enough to keep the compiler happy.

Why is that? What specifically makes the first example fail and the second succeed?

And secondly, is there any way to write the function call so this will not happen, and the user is not faced with having to insert types into the lambda?

Yes, others have asked similar questions but what is unique here is (a) the use of anonymous types (b) the fix by adding types to the lambda.

---

Edited: the problem with the solution given is that it cannot be used with anonymous classes because there is no type annotation possible.

Comment: Look at it this way, you're expecting the compiler to know that `v` was type `int`. But why should it be able to? `T4` could easily be `long`, `double`, `decimal`, or any other type that overloads the addition operator with integers.

Comment: @JeffMercado: No, that isn't it. The compiler is not interested in the form of the expression: you can replace it by anything (valid) without changing the error.

Comment: My point is that the compiler won't go too far out of it's way to try to determine the types for you, at least, not as far as other languages do.  And even if it did try, it wouldn't succeed because the choice would be ambiguous. It will only use the types where it was supplied by you that is fully known. You cannot provide information about the input types but the output types and all you give it is that `T4` could be the result of adding a `T4` with an `int` which is not enough information.

Comment: The issue is that the compiler will go out of its way to figure out the type, but the result **cannot** be ambiguous. Generic type arguments have to be replaced by actual types at compile time. If there is no single type that can be used, then the compiler cannot resolve it and compilation will fail. In those cases, you have to help the compiler and specify the missing types yourself.

Comment: @poke: Sorry, cannot agree. The compiler makes no attempt to perform type inference on the target expression, and replacing it by an integer literal does not resolve the issue. It has nothing to do with ambiguity.

Comment: @david.pfx Replacing `v` in the lambda body with an integer will not help at all, because you still have the parameter `v` (i.e. `(t, v) => 1 + t.Status`). Now `v` is unused so the compiler knows even less about it. Saying *“the compiler makes no attempt to perform type inference”* is just wrong. The whole reason why you do not need to specify actual generic type arguments everywhere is because the compiler does it. Even if you don’t agree, it’s still a fact.

Comment: @poke: no, you really don't get it. The compiler cannot and does not perform type inference _on the target expression_. In the case `(t,v)=>1` the type of `v` is obviously integer but the compiler does not use it. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

The Question is : What is the type of `v` ?

The compiler doesn't infer the type of the input from the expression used as an output. The compiler uses the inferred type of the input to let you write a valid expression for the output. So, `(t, v) => 1` doesn't imply that `v` is of type `int`

This is the compiler trying to analyse your first attempt:

```
var varf1b = varc.F1(t => new { City = t.City }, (t, v) => v + t.Status, (g, a) => new { City = g.City, Bigstatus = a });          
                     |         |                  |  |                    |  |                         |
                     |         |                  |  |                    |  |                         |
              T2: C (varc)     |                  |  ?                    |  ?                         |
                               |                  |                       |                  T1: new { string City,  ? Bigstatus }
                      T3: new { string City }     |                       |
                                                 T2: C                    |
                                                                    T3: new { string City }
```

This is the compiler trying to analyse your second attempt:

```
var varf1b = varc.F1(t => new { City = t.City }, (C t, int v) => v + t.Status, (g, a) => new { City = g.City, Bigstatus = a });          
                     |         |                    |      |                    |  |                         |
                     |         |                    |      |                    |  |                         |
              T2: C (varc)     |                    |    T4: int                |  T4: int                   |
                               |                    |                           |                  T1: new { string City,  int Bigstatus }
                      T3: new { string City }       |                           |
                                                   T2: C                        |
                                                                          T3: new { string City }
```

so `varf1b` is of type : `T1: new { string City,  int Bigstatus }` and the inference succeeds.

A simpler example:

```
private static void GenericMethod<T1>(Func<T1, T1> func)
{
    // ...
}

GenericMethod((a) => 1); // CS0411, `a` is not inferred from the body of the method.

GenericMethod<int>((a) => 1); // compiles

GenericMethod((int a) => 1); // compiles
```

Comment: Note that the compiler doesn’t just need to know that the add operation is supported, but it still needs to know the *actual type* it can use for `T4`.

Comment: @poke in order to know the return type of the `+` method. Right ?

Comment: Not just that but also to resolve the type argument `T4`. Type arguments need to be replaced by “real” types at compile time. They cannot stay generic.

Comment: @user3185569: No, that's not it.  You can replace that expression by anything including an integer literal and the error does not change.

Comment: @david.pfx because you didn't specify the type of `v` which is to be used in the last Func as `a`. The graphics added shows how different `Func`s are related in your case.

Comment: @david.pfx If you write `(t, v) => 1` then what is the type of `a` in the last Func ?

Comment: Your answer is better, but still incomplete, and your simpler example still requires the caller to do the work. See my answer for how to write the function so that type inference succeeds without the caller having to specify any types.

Comment: @david.pfx It is no logical to add a dummy parameter that is not going to be used inside the method, just not to explicitly specify the type of `(C t, int v)`. But since this question is yours, do as you please.

Answer (score -1):

The answer I now see is that the compiler has no information that it can use to determine the type of T4. In particular, it cannot inspect the expression and infer a type from that.

So to fix it we need an argument that explicitly sets the type of T4. Here is one way to do it.

```
  var varf1c = varc.F2(t => new { City = t.City }, 0, (t, v) => v + t.Status, (g, a) => new { City = g.City, Bigstatus = a });

public static T1 F2<T2, T3, T4, T1>(
  this T2 s,
  Func<T2, T3> g,
  T4 i,
  Func<T2, T4, T4> a,
  Func<T3, T4, T1> r)
  where T2 : class where T3 : class where T1 : class {
  return null;
}
```

Now T4 is associated with the literal argument `0`, from which the compiler can infer a type of `int`.

Comment: Modifying the public API just to allow leaving of some more types is a terrible way to solve this. Just specify the type explicitly as you did in the question and you’re fine.

Comment: @poke: No, that's not an answer to the question (see edit). It's not possible to use type annotations when anonymous classes are involved, so the whole point of the questions was to find a way to modify the _function declaration_ to allow type inference to work, and avoid type annotations. Obviously you missed it.